# extracting a string that starts with a specific word/s and ends with a word/s from a list of options

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract some text from a messy data. It looks something like this:

> title: A Game of Thrones author: George R page dimensions: 210 x 297 mm.

They are not always in the same order. I am using python and regex. To solve this I thought I might be able to extract them one by one, but I could not figure out a way to do it. Here is what I have done (showing error`sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0`):

```
import re
text = r'title: A Game of Thrones author: George R page dimensions: 210 x 297 mm.'
re.split(r'*(title)(author|page dimensions)$', text)
```

Comment: Are there always these 3 keys: `title`, `author` and `page dimensions`? If not, are the keys known? If not known, are they all one word (with one exception being `page dimensions`) or not?

Comment: yes, there is always a set of defined titles/keys and some of them are more than one word.

Comment: Then try [this approach](https://ideone.com/Zw19Wa) where `keys` are the words like `title`, `page dimensions`, etc.

Comment: do you want to just extract the needed data or obtain key/value pairs?

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew it does work. Can you please explain the regex?

Comment: @frorekable I posted an answer with explanations.

Comment: Here you go mate. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following approach to build the regex dynamically from the keys since they are known:

```
import re
s = 'title: A Game of Thrones author: George R page dimensions: 210 x 297 mm.'
keys = ["page dimensions", "title", "author"] 
pattern = r"({0}):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:{0}):|$)".format("|".join(keys))
res = dict(re.findall(pattern, s))
print(res)
# => {'author': 'George R', 'page dimensions': '210 x 297 mm.', 'title': 'A Game of Thrones'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nOcBBw)

The `"|".join(keys)` part will build a `page dimensions|title|author` regex given the `keys = ["page dimensions", "title", "author"]` list of keys, and the regex will look like

```
(page dimensions|title|author):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:page dimensions|title|author:|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O2bcq7/2).

**Details**

- `(page dimensions|title|author)` - Group 1: either `page dimensions`, `title` or `author` substring
- `:\s*` - a `:` followed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?=\s*(?:page dimensions|title|author):|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires the following patterns immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:page dimensions|title|author):|$` - either of the 2 alternatives:

    - `(?:page dimensions|title|author):` - `page dimensions`, `title` or `author` followed with `:`
    - `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`(?:(?:title:\s(?P<title>.+?)\s?|author:\s(?P<author>.+?)\s?|page dimensions:\s(?P<dimensions>.+?)\s?)(?=title:|author:|page dimensions:|\.))+`](https://regex101.com/r/OlAuiX/1)

**Python code**:

```
import re

text = """title: A Game of Thrones author: George R page dimensions: 210 x 297 mm.
author: Matteo Norzi page dimensions: 210 x 297 mm title: Icaros: A Vision."""

pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(?:title:\s(?P<title>.+?)\s?|author:\s(?P<author>.+?)\s?|page dimensions:\s(?P<dimensions>.+?)\s?)(?=title:|author:|page dimensions:|\.))+')

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
{'title': 'A Game of Thrones', 'author': 'George R', 'dimensions': '210 x 297 mm'}
{'title': 'Icaros: A Vision', 'author': 'Matteo Norzi', 'dimensions': '210 x 297 mm'}
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/H4Rjke)